# Can a post not be closed for the reason that it is gratuitously disgusting or offensive?

Tags: discussion

This was recently posted, but closed for the reason that insufficient research had been done.

[Do I say butthole or butt hole?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/522710/do-i-say-butthole-or-butt-hole)

Answer (score 5):

If something is offensive (as the middle edit of that question was) then it should be **flagged as offensive**, not close voted. This will delete the post as well as severely penalising the user (if they have any reputation) and if it happens many times, prevent them from posting further.

Answer (score 3):

My approach is a little more subtle than others, perhaps.

Stack Exchange is a collaborative effort. If a question can be edited to remove the offensive part, then that's the right thing to do. Once that's done, it's no longer offensive.

The question might then be closed for other reasons.

Even after the edit, you could still flag it as offensive, because flags are recorded and can be an indicator of trolling activity. Such a flag should be marked helpful, but that doesn't necessarily mean that a penalty would be applied. The penalty is only really applicable if **all** the content is offensive and the post cannot be salvaged, in which case deletion for offence is the right course of action.